# knockout JS formatted number cursor behavior

Tags: knockout.js

Our users started noticing some weird behavior when entering values in input fields.  If they enter 12000 it formats to 12,000 via an extender on the observable.  if they move the cursor behind the comma and delete the first 0 in an attempt to add 500 to the number the cursor moves to the end of the number resulting in 12,005.

It is important that we use valueUpdate:'afterkeydown' to keep the model in sync as they type.

Is there a better (proper) way to handle this?

```
var ViewModel = function() {
this.numberOne = ko.observable(0).extend({ formattedNumeric: null });
this.numberTwo = ko.observable(0).extend({ formattedNumeric: null });
this.addThem = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.numberOne.raw() + this.numberTwo.raw();
}, this).extend({ formattedNumeric: null });
```

};

http://jsfiddle.net/eHjVV/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to throttle the computed which adds comma,  here is the updated jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dhanasekaran/eHjVV/4/

```
ko.extenders.formattedNumeric = function (target) {
    function addCommas(numberString) {
      numberString += '';
      var x = numberString.split('.'),
          x1 = x[0],
          x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '',
          rgxp = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

      while (rgxp.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgxp, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
      }

      return x1 + x2;
    }

    var result = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return addCommas(target());
        },
        write: function (newValue) {
            if ((typeof newValue) === 'string') {
                var num = newValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
                newValue = parseFloat(num);
            }

            if (newValue > 0) {
                target(newValue);
            }
        }
    }).extend({throttle: 500});

    result.raw = target;

    result(target());

    return result;
};
```

Here the comma computation will not happen unless user has stopped typing for at lease 500 millisec. You shall tweak the time to suite the need of your sync speed.

Comment: thank you for the response.  your solution works most of the time but if you time it correctly you can mess up the computed field because of the throttling.  would a custom bindingHandler work for this?  maybe with some custom cursor positioning?

Comment: you are updating the value by using the formatter thats why the cursor is moving to the end. Its like refreshing. If its not so ciritical to show the commas in the input field as the user types, I would just do my processing in the view model or  on the display side (text binding). Custom cursor positioning will be too complicated.

Comment: btw, the commas get messed up even without throttling, I saw this first on my iPad.

Comment: i hadn't noticed the comma getting messed up before.  thanks for pointing that out.  we are trying to find a different solution for this.  maybe a click to edit where we would display the formatted text (text binding) and on click show the unformatted input box for edits.